# What is the second step of this standard normal MGF derivation?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, gaussian-integral

On [this page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Moment_Generating_Function_of_Gaussian_Distribution), it shows the derivation for the MGF of a standard normal density. I don't get why the second step has a $\sqrt{2}\sigma$ which is pulled out from the integral. Can anyone help me understand this?

$$
\begin{aligned}
M_X(t) &= \int \exp(tx) \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \Big( - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big) dx\\
 &= \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \int \exp \Big(tx - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \Big) dx \\
&= \frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \int \exp \Big((\sqrt{2}\sigma u + \mu)t - u^2 \Big) dx \quad\quad u = \frac{x - \mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

I think I follow everything that is going on, but the red term seems to appear for no reason. I must have missed something basic. Where does it come from?

Comment: Last integral should be du

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitution:

$$u=\frac{x-\mu}{\sqrt 2 \sigma}\implies dx=\sqrt 2 \sigma du$$